# How to Configure Gunicorn - Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, gunicorn

I have deployed a Django application on Heroku.
I am using ClearDB - MySQL as Database and trying to populate database with excel file containing data. I have successfully implemented and tested the webapp on localhost using phpmyadmin. The deployed application throws me an application error every time I try to upload the excel file.

Error Logs

[image]

I have tried to update gunicorn configuration but have failed as I do not know how to do that I have tried reading the documentation and have tried running server but there is no effect whatsoever and I have a hunch that it is because something else to be done as it is deployed on heroku not a linux server independently.

The actions I am performing is:

1. reading a excel file in a dataframe
2. cleaning and separating data into multiple tables.
3. running df.to_sql() to upload multiple tables one by one to the MySQL database.

No. of rows 400+

Comment: You write you need help on an urgent basis. But this is not really how stackoverflow works.

Also, you seem to have a problem with Heroku and your call to /import/ timing out or otherwise generating an error. But it's rather hard to understand for us as you do not show any code. Please try and create a small way to reproduce the error.

Comment: You mention that you've deployed a Django app and that you call `df.to_sql()` to populate the database, which does not work. But df is from pandas. I think you should probably try to use Django ORM instead of pandas, and see if you also get an error that way.

Comment: @MichielB Thankyou for responding. I have made a module that directly do populate the db. The problem is I cannot use ORM directly to write changes as I have excelfile that is headerless and have all the tables appended all together in unordered fashion. I tried generating errors by uploading wrong files and portal do recognizes those errors and responds accordingly.